# When should you extend Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I know the basics of multithreading. Moreover, I referred this answer by Mr. Jon Skeet ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread/541506#541506).

Here he said:

> You're not really specialising the thread's behaviour. You're just
>   giving it something to run. (So use Runnable instead of Thread)

So my question is:

**In what scenario one would specialise a thread?**

**When should you extend Thread in Java?**

I would appreciate an answer with examples and codes.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Think about the `Runnable` as a task to execute and about the `Thread` as an executor. You should extend `Thread` if you want to add some specific behavior to executor, like, maybe, controlling its lifecycle, modifying state, etc. An example of classes derived from `Thread` you can find in `JDK`(take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html)), `Android SDK` (take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)).

Answer (score 0):

**One possible scenario is**
When your class is **childclass** i.e. having superclass in that case **you cant extend Thread** , you have to  **implement Runnable interface**
  And if **class is not a childclass** you can extend the Thread class.

Answer (score -1):

One thing which I could think of: If you want to have multiple threads, which by default would have e.g. a specific name or priority, you could extend `Thread`.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public MyThread() {
        super("MyThread");
        setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // something
    }
}
```

Or if you want to make more operations related to the `Thread` object itself. Usually you don't need to do anything else than implement `Runnable` and create the `Thread` with the constructor that takes it as a parameter.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but instead of creating a subclass your chould just create a factory method if you want other default values.

Comment: @JimmyT. Yah, or just use some `Executor`. Was just one thing that could be done.